# How to get account information from huobi API using R

Tags: python, r, api

I am trying to get from huobi API my account information using R.
I got it using python, here it's my code in python

```
import json
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
from urllib.parse import urlencode



def huobi(AccessKeyId, SecretKey):



    timestamp = str(datetime.utcnow().isoformat())[0:19]
    params = urlencode({'AccessKeyId': AccessKeyId,
                        'SignatureMethod': 'HmacSHA256',
                        'SignatureVersion': '2',
                        'Timestamp': timestamp
                       })


    method = 'GET'
    endpoint = '/v1/account/accounts'
    base_uri = 'api.huobi.pro'
    pre_signed_text = method + '\n' + base_uri + '\n' + endpoint + '\n' + params
    hash_code = hmac.new(SecretKey.encode(), pre_signed_text.encode(),hashlib.sha256).digest()
    signature = urlencode({'Signature': base64.b64encode(hash_code).decode()})
    url = 'https://' + base_uri + endpoint + '?' + params + '&' + signature
    response = requests.request(method, url)
    accts = json.loads(response.text)
    print(accts)


   huobi(AccessKeyId = 'AccessKeyId', SecretKey = 'SecretKey')
```

now I want to get it using R

I've tried so many ways to do this in R, my last shot was trying to imitate the code from python in R

```
AccessKeyId <- Sys.getenv("key")
SecretKey <- Sys.getenv("secret")

method <- "GET"

timestamp <- format(now(tzone = "GMT"),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
params <- list(AccessKeyId = Sys.getenv("key"),
               SignatureMethod ='HmacSHA256',
               SignatureVersion = '2',
               Timestamp = timestamp)


params$Signature = hmac(
                    key = SecretKey,
                    object = paste(mapply(paste, names(params), params, 
                             sep = '=', USE.NAMES = FALSE),
                                      collapse = '&'),
                    algo = 'sha256')


 endpoint <- '/v1/account/accounts'
 base_uri = 'api.huobi.pro'
 
url=paste0('https://',base_uri,endpoint,'?',
           paste(mapply(paste,names(params),params,
           sep="=",USE.NAMES = F),
             collapse = "&")
           )


GET(url) %>% 
   pluck("content") %>% 
   rawToChar() %>% 
   fromJSON()
```

at the final of this bring me this error:

```
$status
[1] "error"

$`err-code`
[1] "api-signature-not-valid"

$`err-msg`
[1] "Signature not valid: Verification failure [æ ¡éªŒå¤±è´¥]"

$data
NULL
```

the problem it's with my Singature something in encode the API_KEY it's not working

Comment: You can try posting to a site like https://httpreq.com/ rather than the actual URL to see what's being sent to the server. Then compare the results from the R version and they python version to see what's different.

Comment: thanks, but give me exact what i've expected that the problem it's with my signature.
I found the package Binancer that the @daroczig made, I Went to the source code and copied the signature part and paste to my code to huobi but it isn't working too.
the pre_signed_text it's exact the same in R and python.
I am really confused how to do this kind of encode in R.

Answer (score 0):

just come back to say that i found out the solution for this case here is an example of code:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(httr)
require(jsonlite)
require(base64enc)
require(hash)
require(curl)
require(RCurl)
require(digest)
require(lubridate)


AccessKeyId="key"
SecretKey="secret_key"

timestamp <- format(now(tzone = "GMT"),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
params <- list('AccessKeyId'=AccessKeyId,
             'SignatureMethod'="HmacSHA256",
             'SignatureVersion'='2',
             'Timestamp'=timestamp %>% URLencode(reserved = T))


method = 'GET'
endpoint = '/v1/account/accounts'
base_uri = 'api.huobi.pro'
pre_signed_text = paste(method,
                      base_uri,
                      endpoint,
                      paste(names(params),
                            params, collapse = "&",sep = "="),
                      sep = "\n")

hash_code = hmac(SecretKey, pre_signed_text, algo="sha256", serialize = F, raw = T)

signature <- URLencode(base64encode(hash_code),reserved = T) 

url <- paste('https://',
             base_uri, 
             endpoint, 
             '?',  
             paste(names(params), params,collapse = "&",sep = '='),
             "&Signature=",
             signature,  
             collapse = "&",sep = "")

GET(url) %>%
   pluck("content") %>% 
   rawToChar() %>% 
   fromJSON()
```